# Sort a gridview table only ascending order

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I am trying to sort my gridview by clicking a header and have it sort  only by ascending order.  I am having trouble doing this and any help would be nice.

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Put session variable that has list and store in track results 

        Results trackResults = (Results)Session["Result"];
        GridView1.DataSource = trackResults.results;
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }

    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        //DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

    }
```

Here is the rest for my gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="67px" style="margin-left: 28px" Width="1624px" BackImageUrl='<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="Image"></asp:ImageField>   ' AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="artistViewUrl" DataTextField="artistName" HeaderText="Artist Name" SortExpression="Artist Name" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="collectionViewUrl" DataTextField="collectionName" HeaderText="Collection Name" SortExpression="Collection Name" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="trackViewUrl" DataTextField="trackName" HeaderText="Track Name" SortExpression="Track Name" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="artworkUrl100" HeaderText="Artwork">
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="trackPrice" HeaderText="Track Price" SortExpression="Track Price" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="releaseDate" HeaderText="Release Date" SortExpression="Release Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="primaryGenreName" HeaderText="Genre" />
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Why do the sort expression values have spaces:  SortExpression="Artist Name"?   Shouldn't it be the name of the data column?

Comment: I have the sort expression values the same as my header names of each column. I having trouble sorting when I press on the header column . I'm pulling my information from a RESTful web service and just outing the values I want straight into the gridview ! Just having trouble with how to sort it.